# Modify the ScriptOptions of a ScriptState

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I have a `ScriptState` object that I continuously update with `ContinueWithAsync()`. However, I need the ability to modify the assemblies in use at runtime. I have a `List<MetadataReference>` that I modify occasionally, and use it to store the references. However, basically all of the properties in the `ScriptState` class seem to be immutable, so there isn't a way to modify the references. Can I modify the references of a `ScriptState` object without throwing it away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in a different options each time you call ScriptState.ContinueWithAsync.

```
var newOptions = options.WithReferences(newListOfReferences);
var newState = await state.ContinueWithAsync(newScriptText, newOptions);
```